# wordpress - author slug - page not found

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress for my site `mysite.com` (just considered as an example) and in the  setting of profile i enabled to show `author box` at the bottom of the post.

So at the bottom of the post, I see a box with some image and on the side written as 
`Written by shyma prasad"` Where shyam prasad is a link text which links to `www.mysite.com/author/admin`.

My profile data is as follows.

My profile display name is `shyam prasad` So the written by shows shyam prasad its right. My nickname is `shyam`. 
My login name is `shyam_123`. for username in mysite.com/wp-admin page

I have few questions:

In the url link `www.mysite.com/author/admin` what is the admin, where is came from.

And also when i open this url it shows no content found

There is only one user and is administrator and all the posts are authored by admin. Recently I changed the displayname from `admin` to `Shyam Prasad`

I want `www.mysite.com/author/admin` to be `www.mysite.com/author/shyam`. I tried using plugin called `edit author slug`, but it didnt change `admin` with `shyam` in the url.

Also i want `www.mysite.com/author/shyam` to show author archive.

Can anyone help

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5742/change-the-author-slug-from-username-to-nickname

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('init', 'cng_author_base');
function cng_author_base() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $author_slug = 'profile'; // change slug name
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = $author_slug;
}
```

Comment: But its redirecting to profile/username instead of author/usernickname

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what could be your problem. May be it is wrong impact as you changed the admin name to your name. I would suggest you to take the following steps.

1. create one more account with "your name2" as administrator.
2. Delete the existing account.
3. Move the author using "bulk action" from admin to your account.
4. Remove the "2" from your name.

The Answer which is given by "Vickey" is copy/paste from internet and it is to change the term “profile” instead of “author” in the url which i believe is not your problem.

You can stay in touch with me for wordpress related things.

Regards

Suyash Jain
http://linuxhacks.in